# App Crashing (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) only in RTL Languages like Arabic

Tags: ios, autolayout

App is crashing with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception only in RTL mode whereas the app is working fine in LTR mode.  I'm running the app by forcing it in RTL mode as below,

`Edit Scheme -> Run -> Option -> App Language -> Right to Left Pseudo Language.`

It is crashing in `UIApplicationMain` with following stack trace

```
    0x12495a1bb <+94>:  movq   0x47896(%rip), %rsi       ; "overflowEngineVarIndexForEngine:"
    0x12495a1c2 <+101>: movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x12495a1c5 <+104>: movq   %rbx, %rdx
    0x12495a1c8 <+107>: callq  *0x3d022(%rip)            ; (void *)0x0000000113ecd7c0: objc_msgSend
    0x12495a1ce <+113>: jmp    0x12495a1d5               ; <+120>
    0x12495a1d0 <+115>: movl   $0xffffffff, %eax         ; imm = 0xFFFFFFFF 
    0x12495a1d5 <+120>: movq   0xc0(%rbx), %rcx
    0x12495a1dc <+127>: movl   %eax, %eax
    0x12495a1de <+129>: movq   %rax, %rdx
    0x12495a1e1 <+132>: shrq   $0x6, %rdx
->  0x12495a1e5 <+136>: movq   (%rcx,%rdx,8), %rcx     Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x6190201a4f78)
    0x12495a1e9 <+140>: andl   $0x3f, %eax
    0x12495a1ec <+143>: shlq   $0x5, %rax
    0x12495a1f0 <+147>: leaq   (%rcx,%rax), %r15
```

Crash Log Looks like this

```
Thread 0::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                                    0x110739ad8 ???
1   ???                                    0x111e93948 ???
2   CoreAutoLayout                         0x128b4e3e9 -[NSISEngine negativeErrorVarForBrokenConstraintWithMarker:errorVar:] + 89
3   CoreAutoLayout                         0x128b5716f -[NSISEngine removeConstraintWithMarker:] + 1102
4   CoreAutoLayout                         0x128b6ca30 -[NSLayoutConstraint _removeFromEngine:] + 209
5   UIKitCore                              0x13ecd4dd0 -[UIView _layoutEngine_willRemoveLayoutConstraint:] + 80
6   UIKitCore                              0x13ecd589c -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) nsli_removeConstraint:] + 90
7   CoreAutoLayout                         0x128b6de31 __55+[NSLayoutConstraint _addOrRemoveConstraints:activate:]_block_invoke + 53
8   CoreAutoLayout                         0x128b5458f -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 84
9   CoreAutoLayout                         0x128b6dd0a +[NSLayoutConstraint _addOrRemoveConstraints:activate:] + 398
10  UIKitCore                              0x13ece22f8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 580
11  UIKitCore                              0x13ece344d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 154
12  UIKitCore                              0x13ece4556 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 374
13  UIKitCore                              0x13ede1561 -[UIView _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 352
14  UIKitCore                              0x13edf559f -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2305
15  QuartzCore                             0x11b49302c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 526
16  QuartzCore                             0x11b49e5b9 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 65
17  QuartzCore                             0x11b3afb0c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 626
18  QuartzCore                             0x11b3e769b CA::Transaction::commit() + 735
19  QuartzCore                             0x11b3e8b64 CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) + 60
20  CoreFoundation                         0x11f3df055 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
21  CoreFoundation                         0x11f3d99c2 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 515
22  CoreFoundation                         0x11f3d9f0d __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
23  CoreFoundation                         0x11f3d96a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
24  GraphicsServices                       0x12793128a GSEventRunModal + 139
25  UIKitCore                              0x13e7c2ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 994
26  UIKitCore                              0x13e7c79ef UIApplicationMain + 123
27  libswiftUIKit.dylib                    0x1267f3c72 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 98
28  Bookings                               0x105de34c0 main + 560 (main.swift:12)
29  dyld_sim                               0x1170582bf start_sim + 10
30  dyld                                   0x20cd81310 start + 2432
```

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

I have enabled `Constraint Error Breakpoint` , `Exception Breakpoint` and `Run Time Issue Breakpoint` but have no luck in finding any clue about the issue. Have used instruments to find memory leaks but had no luck there too since it showed as `no leaks`.

So from crash logs it is clear that app is crashing coz of something went wrong inside Autolayout engine (which may be coz of some contradicting constraints) and I can't check all the constraints since app has huge number of them. How can find the root cause of this crash and fix this issue.

I would appreciate any help in finding the root cause of this crash issue.

Comment: Is your app crashing on **Launch**? Or when you **do something**?

Comment: It is crashing on the launch where I render the view which has lot of constraints

Comment: Are you designing your layout (with *"a lot of constraints"*) in Storyboard or via code? I think in order to help you figure this out, we'll need to ***see*** it. Can you create a [mre] with only the first controller?